# Where do you find TikZ/PGF source code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, source

I'd like to check the the source code used to implement the standard rectangle shape in PGF/TikZ. I was thinking about searching for something like `\pgfdeclareshape{rectangle}` inside the PGF files but I have no idea where to look.

I've found a `pgfbaseshapes.sty` file in `texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/` but it is almost empty and tagged as obsolete.

Any hint on where should I look?

It would also be super nice if someone could briefly explain how the PGF/TikZ code is organized into files, i.e. where should one look for the code of a certain shape, a library, etc.

Comment: A lot of them are found in `/usr/local/texlive/<versionnumber>/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/`... You'll find them typically in names that end with `.code.tex`. I can't speak to the organization- I'm sure one of the `tikz` gurus will be around soon :)

Comment: thank you @cmhughes for some obscure reason I was limiting myself to the `tex/latex/` folder... Now I've found all sort of shapes code except that for the standard rectangle :D

Comment: @dcmst: The really basic node shapes (including `rectangle`) are defined in `pgf/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex`

Comment: thanks @Jake. After discovering the right directory to look in (thanks to @cmhughes) I have to say that the files structure is not that complicated as I thought before.

Comment: The parts of the PGF/TikZ bundle that works on any TeX system (plain TeX, LaTeX or ConTeXt) is places in `/tex/generic/pgf` and is then further divided in its layers. I usually throw all PGF files (sometimes including `pgfplots` and or other packages that use TikZ) in Notepad++ and do a search in all files. Libraries oftentimes use the basic stuff anyway so you will wind up switching a lot.

Comment: I generally browse libraries via shell; for example, you can find paths saying `kpsewhere tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex` or `kpsewhere pgflibraryshapes.code.tex` and of course have a look to the code via `nano $(kpsewhere tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex)` or `nano $(kpsewhich tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex)`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel With Notepad++, you don't even need to open the files. Yes, you can search something in all open files, but you can also search something in all files in a folder (from the same dialog, IIRC). I probably miss Notepad++ the most since switching to Ubuntu ...

Comment: @ThomasH: The "advanced find/replace" plugin for gedit does that under ubuntu.

General comment: the `.log` file created when a tex file is compiled lists all packages and files pulled in, which is a good place to start when looking for where something could be defined.

Comment: Side note, there's also https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The first answer is already mentioned in the comments. Basic answer is look for the TeX distro's `tex/pgf/generic` folder. (TikZ/PGF has different implementation details depending on the driver choice so it further classifies code into `ConTeXt/Lua/Xe/PDF/La(TeX)`  etc.) Generic tends to include the driver-independent code.

   To add yet another option from TeXnicCenter, if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and enter `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf` as the Use Directory it will search for all relevant PGF files in a separate `Find` window (for which there are two). A screenshot

   [image]

   Strangely, if it doesn't find anything in a file it says `Cannot access file!` but in fact it does access all files.
2. The organization for the files roughly;

   1. Front-End Layer (TikZ files) `tikz.code.tex` is the main file for everything.
   2. Basic Layer (PGF files)
   3. System Layer (Driver related lowest-level files)
   4. Libraries (PGF versions)
   5. Math, Keys, Utilities etc.

   When we use `\usetikzlibrary{<lib name>}` it looks for the library file

   ```
   tikzlibrary<lib name>.code.tex
   ```

   within the Front-End folder TikZ. However, these library calls also involve

   ```
   pgflibrary<lib name>.code.tex
   ```

   under the hood. So we can also argue that there is a front-end to the libraries too which is mostly used to get the main functionality in a convenient manner and passes onto the actual PGF code.